# connect google cloud sql postgres instance from beam pipeline

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

I want to connect google cloud sql postgres instance from apache beam pipeline running on google dataflow. 
I want to do this using Python SDK.
I am not able to find proper documentation for this.
In cloud SQL how to guide I dont see any documentation for dataflow.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/

Can someone provide documentation link/github example?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **relational_db.Write** and **relational_db.Read** transforms from [beam-nuggets](https://github.com/mohaseeb/beam-nuggets) as follows:

First install beam-nuggests:

```
pip install beam-nuggets
```

For reading:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    source_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
        drivername='postgresql+pg8000',
        host='localhost',
        port=5432,
        username='postgres',
        password='password',
        database='calendar',
    )
    records = p | "Reading records from db" >> relational_db.Read(
        source_config=source_config,
        table_name='months',
    )
    records | 'Writing to stdout' >> beam.Map(print)
```

For writing:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    months = p | "Reading month records" >> beam.Create([
        {'name': 'Jan', 'num': 1},
        {'name': 'Feb', 'num': 2},
    ])
    source_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
        drivername='postgresql+pg8000',
        host='localhost',
        port=5432,
        username='postgres',
        password='password',
        database='calendar',
        create_if_missing=True,
    )
    table_config = relational_db.TableConfiguration(
        name='months',
        create_if_missing=True
    )
    months | 'Writing to DB' >> relational_db.Write(
        source_config=source_config,
        table_config=table_config
    )
```

Comment: To connect to a Cloud SQL DB from Dataflow workers using the Python SDK, I've had to install and run the cloud_sql_proxy CLI on all the workers (or whitelist all IPs for the DB, which is not ideal). I know the Java SDK has some proxy/sockets functionality built in; do you know of any similar tricks for Python @mohaseeb? I'm using beam_nuggets btw, it's working great except for that separate proxy issue :)

Comment: @chmod_007 I don't know of a similar functionality. 

But, you can connect to the DB from your pipleline without "using cloud_sql_proxy" or "whitelisting the worker IPs for the DB" by enabling "Private IP" connectivity on your Cloud SQL DB, and making sure that the Cloud SQL DB and the Dataflow workers are on the same google cloud region (and connecting to the DB using its private IP). For more information check https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip.

Comment: @chmod_007  Nice to see you found beam_nuggets useful; I'll be putting some time over the holidays to work on it.

Comment: The latest docs shows the read method is changed from `relational_db.Read` to `relational_db.ReadFromDB`: http://mohaseeb.com/beam-nuggets/beam_nuggets.io.relational_db.html#beam_nuggets.io.relational_db.ReadFromDB

Answer (score 1):

The Java SDK contains [JdbcIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html) that allows connecting to any database that can be accessed via the standard Java JDBC mechanism. There is currently no analogue in the Beam Python SDK. If there was, I suppose it would be using the Python DB-API. Feel free to file [a feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM) or contribute - it should be fairly straightforward to develop (e.g. by mimicking the source code of the Java `JdbcIO`) but very useful :)

Comment: Thanks @jkff
I am trying to connect using java sdk.
I am able to connect to the postgres instance using proxy and running pipline locally.
But is there any way beam pipeline can directly connect to the cloud sql postgres after deploying on dataflow.
I tried to follow the steps given in 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql-postgres
but it is giving me unknown host for google.
Can you please point me to the documentation for connecting dataflow to postgres cloud sql?

Comment: Can you post a new question with the details of what goes wrong when you try to take the same pipeline that works locally and run it on dataflow?