# Is there any way to update records in postgres sql using beam.Pipeline(relational_db)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

[I have found only write method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129510/connect-google-cloud-sql-postgres-instance-from-beam-pipeline/53623786#53623786)

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
months = p | "Reading month records" >> beam.Create([
    {'name': 'Jan', 'num': 1},
    {'name': 'Feb', 'num': 2},
])
source_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
    drivername='postgresql+pg8000',
    host='localhost',
    port=5432,
    username='postgres',
    password='password',
    database='calendar',
    create_if_missing=True,
)
table_config = relational_db.TableConfiguration(
    name='months',
    create_if_missing=True
)
months | 'Writing to DB' >> relational_db.Write(
    source_config=source_config,
    table_config=table_config
)
```

The above method can be used for writing into the database, but I need to update row based on some value(update table set value where some_condition).

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more details, what have you tried so far, code samples. Having a title and link to another question is bit to less to get an answer.

Comment: I have added some more details, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and have figured out a good (albeit undocumented) solution.

The `TableConfiguration` class takes an optional parameter `create_insert_f`, which expects a function used to generate the `sql` to run the query.  While there are no examples in the main codebase of Beam Nuggets, you can specify an update statement in lieu of the `create_insert_f` (see this [docstring](https://github.com/mohaseeb/beam-nuggets/blob/e79765a69099e6e6a1f635a4fc5be323c0b8da71/beam_nuggets/io/relational_db_api.py#L125-L141)).

For example, for postgres you could write

```
from sqlalchemy import update

def create_update_some_value(table, record):
    update_statement = (
        update(table)
        .where(table.c.uuid == str(record["uuid"]))
        .values(another_value = str(record["some_value"]))
    )
    return update_statement
```

and then pass it into your table configuration like

```
config = TableConfiguration(
            name=MY_TABLE,
            create_if_missing=False,
            primary_key_columns=["uuid"],
            create_insert_f=create_update_some_value,
        )
```

Best of luck!